# Why is my code constantly giving the same random numbers

Tags: random

Whenever I execute the program it always prints out 9 and 5 for sc1 and sc2. It was my understanding that the random class was supposed to be mostly random.

Here is my code:

```
public class BlackJack {

    public static BlackJack blackjack;
    public int chips;
    public static int[] deck;
    public static int ct = 0, sc1, sc2;
    Random random;

    public BlackJack() {
        deck();
        deal();
        System.out.println(sc1);
        System.out.println(sc2);

    }



    public void deck() {
        deck = new int[52];
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            if(i % 4 == 0) {
                ct++;
            }
            deck[i] = ct;
        }

    }



    public void deal() {
        random = new Random(52);
        sc1 = deck[random.nextInt(52)];
        sc2 = deck[random.nextInt(52)];
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        blackjack = new BlackJack();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: You are always seeding your instance of `Random` with 52 so you will always get the same numbers in the pseudo-random sequence.  Take out the 52 in your declaration of `Random`.

Comment: Don't use `Random` class it use a internal dictionary, and can provide you same duplicate data multiple time

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. i'm dumb. It was the fact that i had random = new Random(52); instead of random = new Random();

Comment: You can delete your question/answer